# What is substance that has high melting point in its powder form?

Tags: experimental-chemistry, home-experiment, safety, equipment

In laminated glass bending process 2 glass sheet will be superposed in a furnance.The seperation powder will be interposed between layer for avoid 2 glass sheet being bound together.

I'm trying to find substance that can be replaced baby powder as a lubricant in the process of glass-bending. It has to be cheaper, able to be found as a powder, and it should not be a human hazard.

Recently, I found magnesium sulfate, and I believe that it could be used for my purposes. However, it is so hard to find $\ce{MgSO4}$ in a compact and powdered form.

Does anybody know of any suitable replacements for baby powder in the process of glass-bending?

Comment: Magnesium sulfate (Epsom salt) is easily crushed in a mortar and pestle. If you're using it on molten glass, first dehydrate it (removing water of crystallization) or it will "pop" violently on hot glass.

Comment: Is it ok if i apply it in solution form insted of powder? Is it gonna pop in 630 celcius degree chamber?